# PHP multipage form data across sessions

Tags: php, forms, session

I am working on a multipage form, where users proceed saving data form page to page.
Here is an idea of the flow:

PAGE 1

```
<form action="page2.php" method="POST">
input data_page1
</form>
```

PAGE 2

```
<?php
session_start();
session_register('data_page1');
$_SESSION['data_page1'] = $_POST['data_page1'];
?>

<form action="page3.php" method="POST">
input data_page2
</form>
```

PAGE 3

```
<?php
session_start();
session_register('data_page2');
$_SESSION['data_page2'] = $_POST['data_page2'];
?>

if (!$_SESSION['data_page2']){
echo "Go back to ".'<a href="page2.php">'."page 2".'</a>';
}
else{
<form action="page4.php" method="POST">
input data page3
</form>
}
```

Everything works fine if users input data correctly.

If at page 3 they they forget to input something, they are redirected back to page 2. The problem is that when they are redirected there, the data previously stored from page 1 are lost.

Are sessions the problem here?

Comment: check session value it assign or not if it assigned when page back

Comment: Can you give me an example please?

Comment: Are you just trying to pass data from one page to another?

Comment: Yes, and in the end (after 6 pages) I pass all the data to a table.

Answer (score 0):

its give you an idea how to handle

session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['data_page1']))

{

```
  session_register('data_page1');


  $_SESSION['data_page1'] = $_POST['data_page1'];
```

}

else

{

```
 //user moving back 

 //how you want handle it write here
```

}

Comment: I tried adding to the form the following value:           `value="<?php if(isset($_SESSION['data_page1'])){echo $_SESSION['data_page1'];}?>"`   It works from page2 back to page1, but it doesn't for the others, for example when you are redirected back from page3 to page2.